# Looking for a set of sound sensors with 5 foot capture range

Tags: microphone

I need a few sound sensors that are relatively cheap (under $20 each preferred) that have a capture range of about 5 - 10 feet. It should essentially be just like this product

http://www.emartee.com/product/42148/Mini%20Sound%20Sensor

The only catch is I don't see any info about its strength of capturing sound. I will be placing the sensors at the corners of a room 10x10 (ft) and they need to work for the entire space. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's a pretty nifty little device.  It's also pretty darn cheap.  Why don't you get one for testing?

Answer (score 1):

For your use, distance is not your problem. All distance does is attenuate the signal, do you shouldn't be asking 'Can this pick up sound at 10ft' - instead you should find out the volume you expect at the sensor, and then find the spec of the mic to see if it will give you the signal you need.

That device gives no information about the sound levels it is appropriate for.